# How to calculate the most efficient cut for wooden boards

Tags: optimization, rectangles

I need to know what is the most efficient cut (less remanent and less wooden boards possible) to get the following pieces:

80 pieces sized 50cm x 60cm

80 pieces sized 50cm x 70cm

80 pieces sized 60cm x 70cm

The wooden boards come with a size of 122cm x 244cm.

I know that if i think of total area, i could cover the total area of the pieces with 29 wooden boards, but since there are always remanents, i can´t rely that i will be able to make it with only 29 boards, and if i can, how should i cut the boards in order to achieve that.

Comment: This is known as the 2D cutting stock problem, and there's quite a bit of published research that a web search should turn up.

Answer (score 1):

Using [PowerPoint](https://products.office.com/en/powerpoint) as graphics tool, I manually identified eleven different configurations to place the three different types of pieces on the wooden boards.

[image]

To find the best mix of cutting configurations, I wrote a linear program model for the [GLPK solver](http://winglpk.sourceforge.net/):

```
var x1, >= 0, integer;
var x2, >= 0, integer;
var x3, >= 0, integer;
var x4, >= 0, integer;
var x5, >= 0, integer;
var x6, >= 0, integer;
var x7, >= 0, integer;
var x8, >= 0, integer;
var x9, >= 0, integer;
var x10, >= 0, integer;
var x11, >= 0, integer;
minimize obj: x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6 + x7 + x8 + x9 + x10 + x11;
s.t. ca: 4*x1 + 6*x2 + 8*x3 + 6*x4 + 2*x5 + 3*x6 + 3*x7 +                   4*x10           >= 80;
s.t. cb:                      2*x4 + 2*x5 +        1*x7 +        2*x9 + 2*x10 + 3*x11 >= 80;
s.t. cc: 4*x1 + 2*x2 +               3*x5 + 4*x6 + 3*x7 + 6*x8 + 4*x9 + 2*x10 + 4*x11 >= 80;
solve;
display x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9, x10, x11;
end;
```

The eleven decision variables reflect, how many boards should be cut according to the given configuration.

[GLPK](http://winglpk.sourceforge.net/) came up with the following solution, using just three of the eleven cutting configurations:

```
 8 x type  4 yields 48 x A, 16 x B 
 8 x type 10 yields 32 x A, 16 x B, 16 x C
16 x type 11 yields         48 x B, 64 x C
total               80 x A, 80 x B, 80 x C

A: 80 pieces sized 50cm x 60cm

B: 80 pieces sized 50cm x 70cm

C: 80 pieces sized 60cm x 70cm
```

> According to this solution, 32 wooden boards are needed.